# JavaFx Tableview database not visible eventhough data is loaded

Tags: java, sql, javafx

So I try to show some database value in a tableview for a few hours, at first I couldnt get anything to show but after learning that PropertyValue works with thh getters and after implementing them I could show my data in table, but the problem is some data is not shown and I dont really understand why I looked at my code completley but can not find the mistake, maybe someone can give me a pointer.

In the picture you can see which result I get and which type of data my values have in the sql

Controller Class

```
package Controllers;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import Model.Datenbank;
import Model.flightRouteAddModel;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class FlightRouteOverview implements Initializable {

    public static Connection connection;
    public static Statement statement;
    public Datenbank datenbank;
    overviewAirplaneController controller;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<flightRouteAddModel, String> startAirport;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<flightRouteAddModel, String> targetAirport;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<flightRouteAddModel, String> flightDate;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<flightRouteAddModel, String> airplane;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<flightRouteAddModel, Integer> intervall;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<flightRouteAddModel, Integer> seatCountEco;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<flightRouteAddModel, Integer> seatCountBus;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<flightRouteAddModel, Float> priceEco;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<flightRouteAddModel, Float> priceBus;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<flightRouteAddModel, Float> distance;

    @FXML
    private TableView<flightRouteAddModel> table;

    public FlightRouteOverview() {


    }

    static ObservableList<flightRouteAddModel> flightList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resourced) {


        try {
            verbinden();

            // Ablesen
            Statement pStatement =  connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet myRs = pStatement.executeQuery("select * from fluglinie");
            while (myRs.next()) {
                flightList.add(new flightRouteAddModel(myRs.getString("startFlughafen"), myRs.getString("zielFlughafen"), 
                        myRs.getString("startDatum"), myRs.getInt("intervall"), myRs.getString("flugzeug"), 
                        myRs.getInt("anzahlEconomy"), myRs.getInt("anzahlBusiness"), myRs.getFloat("preisEconomy"), 
                        myRs.getFloat("preisBusines"), myRs.getFloat("distanz")));


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }


        startAirport.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("startAirport"));
        targetAirport.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("targetAirport"));

        flightDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("flightDate"));
        airplane.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("airplane"));
        intervall.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("intervall"));
        seatCountEco.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("seatCountEco"));
        seatCountBus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("seatCountBus"));
        priceEco.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("priceEco"));
        priceBus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("priceBus"));
        distance.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("distance"));

        table.setItems(flightList);


    }

    public void verbinden() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/flugverwaltung?autoReconnect=true&"
                + "useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin", "root", "passwort");

        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

    }

}
```

ModelClass

```
package Model;

import javafx.beans.property.FloatProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleFloatProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class flightRouteAddModel {

    public StringProperty  startAirport;
    public StringProperty  targetAirport;
    public StringProperty  flightDate;
    public IntegerProperty intervall;
    public StringProperty  airPlane;
    public IntegerProperty countEconomy;
    public IntegerProperty countBusiness;
    public FloatProperty   priceEconomy;
    public FloatProperty   priceBusiness;
    public FloatProperty   distance;

    public flightRouteAddModel(String startAirport, String targetAirport, String flightDate,Integer intervall,
                                String airPlane, Integer countEconomy, Integer countBusiness, Float priceEconomy, 
                                    Float priceBusiness, Float distance) {
        super();

        this.startAirport  = new SimpleStringProperty(startAirport);
        this.targetAirport = new SimpleStringProperty(targetAirport);
        this.flightDate    = new SimpleStringProperty(flightDate);
        this.intervall     = new SimpleIntegerProperty(intervall);
        this.airPlane      = new SimpleStringProperty(airPlane);
        this.countEconomy  = new SimpleIntegerProperty(countEconomy);
        this.countBusiness = new SimpleIntegerProperty(countBusiness);

        this.priceEconomy  = new SimpleFloatProperty(priceEconomy);
        this.priceBusiness = new SimpleFloatProperty(priceBusiness);
        this.distance      = new SimpleFloatProperty(distance);


    }

    public String getStartAirport() {
        return startAirport.get();
    }

    public String getTargetAirport() {
        return targetAirport.get();
    }

    public String getFlightDate() {
        return flightDate.get();
    }

    public Integer getIntervall() {
        return intervall.get();
    }

    public String getAirPlane() {
        return airPlane.get();
    }

    public Integer getCountEconomy() {
        return countEconomy.getValue();
    }

    public Integer getCountBusiness() {
        return countBusiness.get();
    }

    public Float getPriceEconomy() {
        return priceEconomy.get();
    }

    public Float getPriceBusiness() {
        return priceBusiness.get();
    }

    public Float getDistance() {
        return distance.get();
    }

}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JTcK.png)

[DatabseType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFoAC.png)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a CellFactory .setCellFactory()
on the column

Tho that is probbaly not the issue. I would guess that the PropertyValueFactory expects the properties to be Strings and not StringProperties. Just make one your own:

```
startAirport.setCellValueFactory(param-> param.getValue().startAirport);
```

Comment: I didnt quite understand what you meant to be honest, the string ones work but the problem is more with the integer ones, eventhough distance is working and it is integer too.

Comment: I tried to do the param.getValue().priceEconomy but now I am getting a typemismatch error it says cannot convert from FloatProperty to observableValue float

Comment: Hey I found the mistake the I had a misspelling in my Propertyvalue it wasnt the same as my getters thanks for all the help

Comment: @user11343077 that's why you shouldn't use PropertyValueFactory at all :) Instead expose properties (best not as public fields as you did, but following the fx property access conventions) and use those in your cellValueFactories. While we are at it: static scope for fields is nearly always _not_ what you want, so better throw them out and replace with proper access methods (if you really need to access them across different classes)